# Building a maven child project that depends on another projects child project with Bamboo

Tags: maven-2, bamboo

I have two maven projects

Project AAA

- AAA-Core
- AAA-Other

Project BBB

- BBB-Core
- BBB-AAA-specific

I want to create a build plan in Bamboo to build the BBB-AAA-specific project. The plan configuration is such that this project depends on the AAA-Other projec build. Thus everything should work ok.

But when I try to run the BBB-AAA-specific Bamboo plan I get an error that states:
"Unable to find resource 'foo.bar.AAA:AAA:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT' in repository snapshots (http://foo.bar.com)"

What is going on?

The bamboo builds for "AAA-Core" and "AAA-Other" work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out this myself:

The AAA-Other module's pom.xml depends on the parent projects (AAA) pom.xml.
The error message from building the BBB-AAA-specific project means that the snapshot of the AAA project is not available in the local maven repository ie. it has not been installed there.

To overcome this, I created a separate Bamboo build plan just for the AAA parent project that handles the installation of just the parent project, not any of the child projects. This was accomplished with the following builder goal:

```
--non-recursive clean install
```

What this does, is that the parent project is built and installed without the child projects. This in turn guarantees that the AAA projects pom.xml is available in the local maven repository and the BBB-AAA-specific Bamboo build may then use it as a dependency.